# With jQuery, how do I get the height an element would have if I set it to fit-content?

Tags: jquery

I am building a calendar to show events on a web page. The height of these elements is defined by the start time and end time, so sometimes their height is not enough to show all information.
To fix that, I am using jQuery to switch height to 'fit-content' when onmouseover is triggered, then I set it back to 'inherit' onmouseout.
The event div looks like this (grid-row-start and grid-row-end are calculated by PHP based on the start and end time)

```
<div class="event-container" onmouseover="event_over(this);" onmouseout="event_out(this);" style="grid-row-start: 10; grid-row-end: 15;">
Information on the event...
</div>
```

and jQuery:

```
function event_over(el) {
    $(el).css({'z-index': 3, 'height': 'fit-content'});
}

function event_out(el) {
    $(el).css({'height': 'inherit', 'z-index': 2});
}
```

This works fine when an event heigh is too small to show its full content, but when the event height is big enough my function does the opposite: it shrinks the event to the minimum necessary height, then sets it back onmouseout.

I would like to turn my jQuery into something like this:

```
function event_over(el) {
    if ( current_height < full_height_when_I_set_you_to_fit-content ) $(el).css({'z-index': 3, 'height': 'fit-content'});
}

function event_out(el) {
    $(el).css({'overflow': 'hidden', 'height': 'inherit', 'z-index': 2});
}
```

I've played around with .height, .outerHeight and some other jQuery methods, but I couldn't find the right ones to create the condition correctly.